# Recovering data after unity crash after installing radeon driver

Tags: unity, data-recovery

I installed a graphics driver (for radeon in dell )  from ubuntu software center. when the system restarted the sidebar is not appearing after login. Before login at least few icons appear at top right. After log in nothing appears & I cannot even open  terminal using "ctrl + alt + t". Even the guest session does not work !
 When I tried "ctrl + alt + del" during boot to start in recovery mode, it still boots & this time the touchpad or mouse is not working.

I should have not gambled since I recently migrated completely to Ubuntu overwriting Windows. Is there a way to solve this problem or at least can I recover the data from the system; allowing me to reinstall the OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to press `CTRL + ALT + F1` to get a virtual console and log in to recover data using the command prompt and fix your drivers. To revert back to a GUI session siply press `CTRL + ALT + F7`. Alternatively, you can get the grub menu by pressing `shift` while booting and the boot into recovery to get a command prompt.

Once you have the command prompt you can remove the AMD drivers

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
```

You can now reinstall xorg

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg
```

and then

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Comment: I use Ubuntu 14.04 & I tried CTRL + ALT + F1  using virtual keyboard but nothing visible happens. The problem is that I am not able to get the terminal. Are there any way to get into recovery mode? @Ubuntu_kwr

Comment: I am able to get into recovery mode by pressing shift during boot, can I do something now? When I execute 'sudo apt-get purge fglrx*' it says dpkg was interupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem

Comment: thanx I solved the problem using the above comments after repairing using dpkg in boot menu from recovery mode. But the screen quality looks less better now!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get into the grub menu by pressing `shift` as your computer boots. One of the options should be 'recovery mode' or something similar. From there you should be able to get into a root shell.

Once you're in the recovery menu, select the `dpkg` option.

When that's finished, press enter to return to the recovery menu and then select the `root` option

After that try running `sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*`